pymongo objectid to string on pandas
I own a Dataframe that is built over a pymongo query. I´ve imported the records to a pandas dataframe.
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bson import ObjectId
a = {'_id': ObjectId('6127ada0462851531ed3ee14'),
 'referenciaConversao': ObjectId('6123ca19b2dc56c529479733'),
 'nomeProduto': 'Fire TV Stick Lite com Controle Remoto Lite por Voz com Alexa (sem controles de TV) | Streaming em Full HD | Modelo 2020'}
pd_conversão = pd.DataFrame.from_records([a])
pd_conversão


Now, I am using str.strip() over some of the columns to remove unexpectected space.
The question is that after I apply the method, it returns a NaN as result, because of despite of the column is of a string type, it still behaves as a object.
pd_conversão['teste'] = pd_conversão['referenciaConversao'].str.strip(' ')
pd_conversão


I´ve seen on strip() method documentation that it returns NaN for everything else that is not a string. But how to I solve this? I´ve seen some questions that talks about iterating about every single row! I have a huge DF, so that is not an option!
I´ve tried to convert my column (astype) to string, but does not work!

Column 'referenciaConversao' contains ObjectId objects, and not str.
ObjectId will raise an error if it is called with an invalid string, including one with trailing spaces:

bson.errors.InvalidId: '6123ca19b2dc56c52947973 ' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

If this is being imported as ObjectId, they won't have trailing spaces and you shouldn't need to use strip. If you're creating the objects yourself, you should strip the strings before creating the objects.

You can cast the Object id to str like this:
pandas_data_frame["_id"] = str(pandas_data_frame["_id"])

And then remove unecessary remaining characters with:
pandas_data_frame["_id"] = pandas_data_frame["_id"].str.replace(r"[^0-9]+", "")

